# Delegate ansible playbook to third hosts

Tags: configuration, ansible, remote-server

I have a playbook which copies distributions to `Jumphosts` and prepares configuration files to deploy on remote servers.
[image]

Question: `import_playbook` cannot be used with `delegate_to`. How can I run playbook on `Jumphost` with generated hosts and playbook from distributions?

Update: I cannot control `Jumphost` and cannot use ssh forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"How to run playbook on 'Jumphost' with generated hosts and playbook from distributions?"*

A: It's possible to create dynamic inventory groups with the module `add_host`. For example, let's assume we want to deploy all intranet hosts running Ubuntu disco.

Create the inventory

```
$ cat hosts
Host1 ansible_host=10.11.0.3
Host2 ansible_host=10.11.0.4
Host3 ansible_host=10.11.0.5
Host4 ansible_host=10.11.0.6
```

Create a playbook to deploy the hosts in the group `my_ubuntu_disco_group`

```
$ cat deploy-Ubuntu-disco.yaml
- hosts: my_ubuntu_disco_group
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

Run a playbook that creates the dynamic group and imports the play.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: my_ubuntu_disco
      loop: "{{ groups.all }}"
      when:
        - hostvars[item].ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
        - hostvars[item].ansible_distribution_release == 'disco'
      run_once: true

- import_playbook: deploy-Ubuntu-disco.yaml
```